# The selected value should show alert msg

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter, jquery

In the below **codeigniter** code i have placed the **controller,model** and **view** part. My aim is if i select exam name from the dropdown it should alert the selected `exam`. My actual result is if i select exam name it throws "hai" alert msg not the exam name. Please solve my issue.

**controller:**

```
public function index()

    {   
//echo "inside form upload";   

        $data = array();
        //$college_name = $this->session->userdata('college_name');
        if($query = $this->import_model->get_exam_data())
        {
            $data['exam_data'] = $query;
        }
        //$this->load->view('student_view', $data);

        $this->load->view('form_upload',$data);
    }
```

---

**model:**

```
function get_exam_data()
    {
        $this->db->distinct();
        $this->db->select("CONCAT(exam_name) AS fullexamname", FALSE);//this will concat the value
        //$this->db->where('college_name',$college_name);
        $query = $this->db->get('examcourse');
        return $query->result();
    }
```

---

**view:**

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
 function get_subjectcodedetails() {
alert("hai");
        //var course_name = jQuery('#course_name_id').val();
        var exam_name = jQuery('#exam_name_id').val();

        //alert("course_name"+course_name);
        alert("exam_name"+exam_name);
        jQuery.ajax({
        data: '&exam_name='+exam_name,
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'import/subjectcodedetails',
        success: function(data){
            //alert("inside change"+data);
            console.log(data);
            jQuery('#ssubject_code').html(data);
        }
    });

} 
</script>
<form action="http://localhost/CodeIgniter/index.php/import/upload" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" enctype="multipart/form-data">        <?php 
        $data = array();
        $data["Select Exam Name"] = "Select Exam Name"; 
        foreach ($exam_data as $row)
        {
            $data[$row->fullexamname] = $row->fullexamname; 
        }
        echo form_dropdown('exam_name', $data, 'small', 'class="dropdown_class"  id="exam_name_id" onChange="get_subjectcodedetails()"');
?>
<div id="ssubject_code">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try like this

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
 function get_subjectcodedetails(obj) {        
    var exam_name = obj.value; // getting value        
    alert("exam_name"+exam_name);
    jQuery.ajax({
    data: 'exam_name='+exam_name,
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'import/subjectcodedetails',
    success: function(data){
        //alert("inside change"+data);
        console.log(data);
        jQuery('#ssubject_code').html(data);
    }
});

} 
</script>
<form action="http://localhost/CodeIgniter/index.php/import/upload" method="post"     accept-charset="utf-8" enctype="multipart/form-data">        <?php 
    $data = array();
    $data["Select Exam Name"] = "Select Exam Name"; 
    foreach ($exam_data as $row)
    {
        $data[$row->fullexamname] = $row->fullexamname; 
    }
    echo form_dropdown('exam_name', $data, 'small', 'class="dropdown_class"  id="exam_name_id" onChange="get_subjectcodedetails(this)"');
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

may I suggest to remove

```
 alert("hai");
```